# Route exists, but getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, cancan

I am trying this code in my application layout. its a "user navigation" bar at the top of the screen.

```
<%= link_to "My Profile", edit_profile_path, :class => "user_nav_button" %>
```

I am getting

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}

However, rake routes shows:

> edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit

If i directly go to **/profiles/1/edit** my view works, and the link_to shows..........

I think it has something to do with not getting the params properly... I am using devise/cancan/rolify and current_user.id is my param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That path method call requires an instance of the object. Otherwise Rails doesn't know which user profile you want to edit and it doesn't guess.

```
edit_profile_path(@user) # Where @user is an instance of a User model from your controller
```

Comment: I fixed it by using edit_profile_path(current_user.profile.id) thanks! @user wouldnt work as it is not globally available

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the id to be shown on the address bar, you should add a new route to something like /profile/edit without ids and, on the controller, get the id of the current_user

otherwise use edit_profile_path(@user) like patrickmcgraw said above

Comment: I will be doing this eventually. thank you... just want to get it all working, then i'll be cleaning up URL conventions

Comment: Is it possible to setup a custom route for something like  `cars_path(:user_id => current_user.id)` where it shows **www.site.com/cars?user_id=1** in the address?

Comment: do something like match '/cars?user_id=:user_id', :to => 'controller#action', :as => 'cars', :user_id will be on the params hash